# Как реализовать вывод списка рубрик кастомной записи?

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю простой каталог на базе Custom Post Type

Создал кастомную запись с возможностью добавления рубрики

```html
<?php
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type_project() {

 $labels = array(
  'name'                  => 'Галерея',
  'singular_name'         => 'Gallery',
  'menu_name'             => 'Галерея',
  'add_new_item'          => 'Добавить новый',
  'add_new'               => 'Добавить новый',
  'new_item'              => 'Новая',
  'edit_item'             => 'Редактировать',
  'update_item'           => 'Обновить',
  'view_item'             => 'Просмотр',
  'view_items'            => 'Посмотреть все',
 );
 
 $rewrite = array(
  'slug'                  => 'gallery',
  'with_front'            => true,
  'pages'                 => false,
  'feeds'                 => false,
 );
 $args = array(
  'label'                 => 'Галерея',
  'labels'                => $labels,
  'supports'              => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'),
  'taxonomies'            => array('category'),
  'hierarchical'          => false,
  'public'                => true,
  'show_ui'               => true,
  'show_in_menu'          => true,
  'menu_position'         => 7,
  'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-image',
  'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
  'can_export'            => true,
  'has_archive'           => true,  
  'exclude_from_search'   => true,
  'publicly_queryable'    => true,
  'query_var'             => 'gallery',
  'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
 );
 register_post_type( 'gallery', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_project', 0 );
```

разобрался с выводом записей

на этой же странице появилось необходимость в сайдбаре вывести список рубрик

я добавил

**wp_list_categories()**

но он выводит все категории которые есть на сайте,

нужно  вывести только рубрики этой кастомной записи

как решить подкиньте идею

Answer (score 1):

У кастомных типов записей не категории, а таксономии. Получить и вывести их можно таким кодом:

```
$args = array(
    'object_type' => array( 'gallery' ),
);
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args );
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>'. $taxonomy. '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу примерно так в function.php создал кастомную таксономию для этой записи

```html
function gallery_categories() {
    $field_args = array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name'              => 'Галерея', 'taxonomy general name',
        'singular_name'     => 'Галерея', 'taxonomy singular name',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Categories',
        'all_items'         => 'Все',
        'parent_item'       => 'Parent Галерея',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Category:',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Category',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Category',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Добавить новую',
        'new_item_name'     => 'Новая',
        'menu_name'         => 'Рубрика Галереи',
        ),
        'hierarchical' => true
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'gallery_categories', 'gallery', $field_args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'gallery_categories', 0 );
```

и в шаблоне добавил

```html
<?php   $terms = get_terms( 'gallery_categories' );
        if( $terms && ! is_wp_error($terms) ){
            foreach( $terms as $term ){
           echo '<ul class="product-categories">'; 
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';
       echo '</ul>';   
        }
    }
   ?>
```

**список вывелся**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]